# dht nodes in Libtorrent

Tags: libtorrent

How can I increase the number of dht nodes?

Current number is about 240:

```
app['lt_session'].status().dht_nodes)
```

While uTorrent says it has about 500 ones.

Here is the settings:

```
async def lt_session(app):
    ses = app['lt_session'] = lt.session({
        'active_downloads': 50,
    })
    ses.listen_on(6881, 6881)
    # ses.set_max_connections(3)
    ses.add_extension('ut_metadata')
    ses.add_extension('smart_ban')
    ses.add_extension('ut_pex')
    ses.add_extension('metadata_transfer')
    ses.add_dht_router("router.utorrent.com", 6881)
    ses.add_dht_router("router.bittorrent.com", 6881)
    ses.add_dht_router("dht.transmissionbt.com", 6881)
    ses.add_dht_router("dht.aelitis.com", 6881)
    ses.add_dht_router("router.bitcomet.com", 6881)
    ses.start_dht()
    ses.start_lsd()
    app['torrents'] = {}
```

Comment: does uTorrent include nodes in replacement buckets in its count?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an "extended routing table", and a depth of 19 (which I believe is about how large the network is), you end up having `128+64+32+16+(15*8)` = 360 nodes in the regular routing table buckets (once it fills up). In 
addition to this, each level has 8 replacement buckets, so + (19*8).

libtorrent's `node_count` only count the nodes in the main routing table buckets, the ones that are used. If you want to count the replacement nodes too, add `dht_node_cache`.

If you want to make sure your routing table fits as many nodes as possible, and is the least restrictive of which nodes are allowed to be added:

Make sure you set `dht_extended_routing_table` to true.
If you want to remove restrictions about which nodes are let into the routing table you can set:

- `dht_restrict_routing_ips` to `false`
- `dht_restrict_search_ips` to `false`

Also, if you have multiple external IPs, you may want to make sure to enable listening to all of them, as libtorrent will run a DHT node for each. For example if you have bot hIPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Thank you @Arvid, how can I set ```dht_extended_routing_table ``` to true?
```KeyError: 'unknown name in settings_pack: dht_extended_routing_table'``` - have such error. Didn't find anything about it in documentation.

Comment: It should default to true. the `settings_pack` in python is just a dict, so: `ses.apply_settings({'dht_extended_routing_table': 1})`

Comment: got error ```KeyError: 'unknown name in settings_pack: dht_extended_routing_table'``` when do 
```ses.apply_settings({'dht_extended_routing_table': 1})```. And when I print ```app['lt_session'].get_settings()``` - I don't have ```dht_extended_routing_table``` here

Comment: you may have a very old version of libtorrent

Comment: version is 1.1.5.0 apt-get install -y python3-libtorrent

Comment: in libtorrent 1.1.x you can instead use `session::set_dht_settings()` and set `dht_settings::extended_routing_table`

Comment: thank you. Could you please tell is there a way to get more peers? I run one torrent, handle.status().num_peers says about 8-10, while at the same time uTorrent says it has about 25 peers for the same torrent (I use magnet link in both cases). And also uTorrent download speed is much higher.

Comment: make sure you can receive incoming connections, over both uTP and TCP. There's also this: http://libtorrent.org/troubleshooting.html

Comment: how can I check it (that I can receive incoming connections)?

Comment: I have this in my settings:    'enable_outgoing_utp':True,
   'enable_incoming_utp':True,
   'enable_outgoing_tcp':True,
   'enable_incoming_tcp':True

Comment: telnet says, connection ok